# Unable to submit to AppStore with Xcode 6 GM Seed

Tags: xcode

Anyone else having issues submitting iOS8 apps to AppStore using Xcode 6 GM Seed released 2014-09-09?

Keep running in to this error:

> This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7
>   SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software.

My understanding was that the GM SEED is the version which allow you to submit iOS8 enabled app to the App Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the GM seed is one which can be used to submit updated apps. However, Apple typically send out an email once developers are clear to submit apps built with the GM seed. That hasn't happened yet.

Due to the new phone sizes I expect there will also be updates to iTunes Connect first to support the new screen sizes. I would recommend allowing a day for them to sort all of that. If it is still not available then contact Apple support directly.

**Update**: Apple have now sent out the email indicating submissions for iOS 8 are now open. Try again now.

Comment: The confusion is most likely from this
[Apple news link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09082014b)

I would keep looking to see if Apple has any updates. Also they just rebooted ITC so it should be ready for iOS8 Submissions.

Answer (score -1):

I guess maybe you Archived your app in xcode beta and tried to submit it in xcode GM?
I just submitted my iOS 8 app with Xcode GM yesterday and it was totally fine and is now under review.